# How to remove line breaks but retain paragraphs

Tags: text-editing, fill-paragraph, line-break

I have `fill-column` set to 75 by default and use `fill-paragraph` to insert line breaks in the paragraphs of text that I write. On certain occasions though, I need to remove the line breaks but want to retain the spacing between the paragraphs. Up until now I used to set `fill-column` to a very large number, then filled the entire selected region, and then went back to the default 75. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Dan :) Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!